# Get the number of duplicated elements in a set

Tags: c++

So a set doesn't allow duplicates, but is there a way, or another data structure, that can allow me to get the number of repeated elements even though they have been removed?. Let me explain myself better anyways.

Lets say I'm giveng this input:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3]
```

If I put it in a set, it will end up like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Which is what I want, but how can I know that there were three 2s before they were removed? Isn't this related to those data structure with "buckets" or something?

Basically I'd like the output to be something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5]
 |  |  |  |
[1, 3, 2, 1]
```

With the bottom array being the number of duplicates of each element on the top array.

Comment: The data structure you are thinking of is a "bag". C++ calls this a `std::multiset`.

Comment: how did you insert them into the set? via `std::set::insert` ? It has a return value that tells you if the element was present before. All you need to do is count

Comment: @Botje But I think a multiset keeps the duplicates. I actually want them removed but still know how many there were before they were removed, does that make sense?

Comment: you can use a `std::map< Key,Value>` to count frequencies. `Key` is the numbers and `Value` is their frequency

Comment: do you want to have the information in the container ? Then its a `std::map`. Or do you want to store it separate from the container? THen its a `std::set`

Comment: imho the question is unclear. A set does only store unique elements, hence you cannot count "duplicate elements in a set". How to know that there were three 2s ? You look at the original data and count the 2s. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah I know its a weird question. Let me edit it and I'll show you what I'm looking for

Comment: you want to count frequencies. There are plenty of quesitons about this. use a `std::map< number , frequency >`

Comment: Technically, `[1, 2, 3, 5]` does not denote a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `std::map` to count the frequency of the items.

For example:

```cpp
int arr[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3};

std::map<int, int> count;

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    count[arr[i]]++;
}

for (auto& [element, frequency] : count) {
    std::cout << element << " : " << frequency << endl;
}
```

The output would be something like this:

```
1 : 1
2 : 3
3 : 2
5 : 1
```

Comment: 1 minute faster than me. Only difference `for (const auto & ....` for printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You gave the answer yourself: if suffices to keep counts *in correspondence* to the unique elements. Hence a compact data structure is the list of the unique elements paired with the list of counts *in the same order*.

Now how this is obtained depends on how you plan to remove the duplicates and the kind of access desired. One way is to sort the initial list, purge the duplicates at the same time that you count them and fill the list of counts. Another way is to use a map with the list elements as keys and associate them with a count. Whether you keep the map or fill new lists is your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The number of duplicate elements in a set in C++ can be determined by using the `size()` function and subtracting the number of unique elements in the set, which can be found by using the `unique()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
std::set<int> mySet;
mySet.insert(1);
mySet.insert(2);
mySet.insert(2);
mySet.insert(3);
mySet.insert(3);
mySet.insert(3);

int numDuplicates = 0;
int lastElement = -1;
for (int element : mySet) {
    if (element == lastElement) {
        numDuplicates++;
    }
    lastElement = element;
}

std::cout << numDuplicates << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```